# How to copy a char to a string made by pointers?

Tags: c

So, I have a string of chars made by a pointer

```
char * string ="123456";
```

I also have two chars

```
char character1 = '7';
char character2 = '8';
```

I would like to  substitute the 2 first positions of the pointer string by the two other chars, so the final string pointer is "783456".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

With the line

`char * string ="123456";`

you made `string` point to a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal), which is read-only.

Attempting to modify a string literal will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (i.e. it is not allowed and may cause the program to crash).

If you want to modify the string `"123456"`, you must first copy it to a memory location that is writable and then make the changes, for example like this:

```
//these declarations were taken over from the question
char * string = "123456";
char character1 = '7';
char character2 = '8';

//this will copy the string to a writable memory location
char buffer[7];
strcpy( buffer, string );

//this will modify the string
buffer[0] = character1;
buffer[1] = character2;
```

Or you can initialize the writable memory to `"123456"` in the first place, so that you don't have to first copy it from a pointer to a string literal.

```
char buffer[] = "123456";
buffer[0] = '7';
buffer[1] = '8';
```

Comment: So how could I create another vector to concatenate the two chars and the part of the string I want?

Comment: Great point. Unfortunately it will compile in many compilers. See https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=87152066#content/view/87152066. Ideally, one should use const with string literals.

Comment: @blackbrandt, thank you very much. How can I copy the vector back to the pointer?

Comment: @Noob: You cannot copy the modified string back to the pointer `string`, as the pointer itself is unable to contain a string and the memory that the pointer is pointing to is read-only. However, you can make the pointer `string` point to the string in writable memory, like this: `string = buffer;`. Afterwards, you can modify the string through the pointer. For example, you can write `string[0] = '9';`, which is equivalent to `buffer[0] = '9';`, since `string` is now pointing to `buffer`.

Comment: "which is read-only" and "cannot copy the modified string back to the pointer string" are amiss.  Attempting to write is UB - bad to do as answer explains, yet it _might work_, might not.  C does not specify any read-only memory.

Comment: @chux: From the perspective of a programmer who doesn't want to invoke undefined behavior, the memory location of a string literal is read-only. Therefore, I consider my wording appropriate in the context of explaining something to a beginner, even if it is not fully accurate. In the sentence afterwards, I clarified my remark by referring to undefined behavior and providing a link to the corresponding Wikipedia article. Doing anything more, such as using the fully correct terminology everywhere in my answer, would probably have confused the OP more than helping them.

Answer (score -1):

You can use another pointer to copy first the chars and then the rest of the string.  You can try:

```
char *string2;
string2[0]=7;
string2[1]=8;
string2[2]=..
```

OR you can use lists.  Using these functions you can create one and add to the beginning:

```
typedef struct elem {
  int n;                          
  struct elem *next;      
}elem;

elem *adds(elem *list,int n) {
  return new(n,list);
}

elem *new(int n,elem *next) {
  elem *e=(elem*)malloc(sizeof(elem));
  if(!e) {
    printf("Memory failure");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  e->n=n;
  e->next=next;
  return e;
}
```

Comment: You may want to review the [help page on how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Meanwhile someone else has fixed the formatting of your code for you.